# How to Directly Retrieve Data from PHP to Flutter Application?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, flutter

I'm currently developing a Flutter application with a PHP MySQL backend. I need guidance on how to retrieve data from a PHP file and display it within my Flutter app. Specifically, I want to fetch the $dept variable from the PHP snippet below and utilize it in my Flutter widget or store it for further processing:

```
            <?php
            session_start();
            include_once ('config.php');

            $lg_username = $_REQUEST['lg_username'];
            $lg_password = $_REQUEST['lg_password'];
            $lg_password = md5($lg_password);

            $sql = "SELECT lg_username, lg_name, lg_dp_code FROM hr_login WHERE lg_username = '$lg_username' AND lg_password = '$lg_password'";
            $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            $userRow = mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $user = $userRow['lg_username'];
            $name = $userRow['lg_name'];
            $dept = $userRow['lg_dp_code'];
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($res);

            if($count == 1){
                return $dept;
            }else{
                echo json_encode("Error");
            }
            ?>
```

I'm trying to achieve this within the _saveCheckIn method:

```
  Future _saveCheckIn() async {
      var url = Uri.http(
          "192.168.68.216", '/ump_attendance_2/save_check_in.php', {'q': '{http}'});
      var response = await http.post(url, body: {
        "lg_username": user.lg_username,
        "lg_password": user.lg_password
      });
      //call the string data from php file
    }
```

I appreciate any assistance you can provide. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to use `echo json_encode($dept);` instead of `return $dept;`
Next you might want to connect the debugger in Flutter  and set a breakpoint to check what is in the `response` object

Comment: And how should I wrote the codes in the flutter to return $dept as I call the function?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json_encode($dept) instead of $dept on the php side. After that, you can check data like below and return $dept data and use the futurebuilder.

```
Future _saveCheckIn() async {
  var url = Uri.http(
      "192.168.68.216", '/ump_attendance_2/save_check_in.php', {'q': '{http}'});
  var response = await http.post(url,
      body: {"lg_username": user.lg_username, "lg_password": user.lg_password});
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return json.decode(response.body); 
  } else {
    print('Something wents wrong');
  }
}
```

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: _saveCheckIn(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.done:
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text(snapshot.data);
            }
            return const Text('What do you want');

          default:
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
        }
      },
    )
```